# Spring REST @RequestBody consume (XML or JSON) to POJO without annotations

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, jaxb

I am writing a Springboot REST endpoint and want to consume XML or JSON requests for a simple service. In either case I want Spring to construct an @RequestBody pojo WITHOUT annotating any of the POJO. Is this OK? Safe? Performant?

I was reading [this](https://dzone.com/articles/jaxb-no-annotations-required) which told me about configuration by exception. To me this means if I structure my request to contain the exact name and case as the POJO member variables I want to populate the @RequestBody will be able to create my class SomeRequest.

If this is my REST endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = GET_FOR_SOMETHING, method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE},,
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody
StatusResponse<Boolean> getMpdForReqest(@RequestBody SomeRequest request)
```

And this is my POJO:

```
public class SomeRequest {

    String one;
    String two;


    public String getOne() {
        return one;
    }

    public void setOne(String one) {
        this.one = one;
    }

    public String getTwo() {
        return two;
    }

    public void setTwo(String two) {
        this.two = two;
    }
}
```

My JSON request:

```
{
"one": "str",
"two": "str"
}
```

My XML request:

```
<SomeRequest>
   <one>str</one>
   <two>str</two>
</SomeRequest>
```

My question is: why should I not do this or is it perfectly fine?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR;** It is perfectly fine.

> **Is this OK? Safe? Performant?**

Yes, it is as performant as it's annotated cousin, if you take program efficiency into account.

If you take the Programm**er** efficiency into account, it is much more efficient as the developer doesn't have to deal with a bunch of annotations.

Speaking of Programm**er** efficiency, I would encourage you to use project Lombok instead of crapping your POJO with bunch of getter and setter methods, that's what cool kids do now a days.

**Catch**

This will work fine as long as your json fields are one word and small case.

When you have multi-word field name, Java standard is the `camelCase` and usually JSON standard is the `snake_case`. In this case, you can either have a Class level Annotation (one per class, so not much ugly). Or, since you are using spring boot, you can use an application wide property (`spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy = SNAKE_CASE` ).

If you have weird json field names with spaces in between, you might need to use `@JsonProperty` annotation. Remember, this is a perfectly valid json

> ```
> {
>     "just a name with a space" : "123"
> }
> ```

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get the XML response unless I include

     `   <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency> `

in my pom.xml. 

With it, everything does work without any special annotations.

Answer (score 0):

POJO as `RequestBody` works perfectly fine. Just note that Spring however will return `400 - Bad Request` for every request that can not be mapped to the `@RequestBody` annoted object.